# Should I use both Django views and Rest Framework together and how?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I will create a web app that mostly depends on basic CRUD operations but may change in the future (like getting data from another web service). I also will create a mobile app for my web app as well in order to do the same CRUD ops and the mobile app will use the REST API of my web app.

So the question is that which way should I follow to accomplish these plans? Should I first create the REST API and then use it in my regular Django templates? Or should I create both the Django template views (CBVs, i.e. CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, ListView) and also REST API views separately?

I really confused as I don't know what people do for such apps. Can you help me to have a roadmap? What would you do and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just create an `api` app, which just has DRF views, serializers, routers, permission classes etc (just holds all the rest framework objects). Your other apps would be normal django apps holding your models CBVs forms etc.

Then for example, when you're creating serializers, you'd just have `from myapp.models import MyModel` to reference the app specific models.

I've used this structure before and it seemed to work pretty well.

```
api
 - serializers.py
 - viewsets.py
 - custom_permissions.py
 - urls.py
 - routers.py
app_1
 - views.py
 - models.py
 - forms.py
 - tests
     - test_models.py
     - test_views.py
 - urls.py
app_2
 - views.py
 - models.py
 - forms.py
 - tests
     - test_models.py
     - test_views.py
 - urls.py

manage.py
etc etc
```

Comment: But, isn't it bad for the Do Not Repeat Yourself principle since you have to write the same code in the views of the Django apps and the REST API? For example, when you create a post, you will send a request to some services (Akismet for checking spam, twitter to send a message to a related user etc). You will have to take these actions in both of the views (Django apps and REST API). Am I wrong? Or is it OK to repeat yourself that much for such projects?

Comment: I think the Django rest framework reduces the amount of code you have to write significantly with things like viewsets and modelviewsets, so you’re not really repeating code all that much,
and if you have functionality that’s called when a post is saved for example, you can use signals for post_create or override the save method of the object so you only have that logic in one place